# Subset of absolutely continuous functions is Banach

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ denote the subspace of absolutely continuous functions from $[a,b]\to\mathbf{R}$ whose derivative is in $L^p[a,b]$. We define a norm of $A$ by setting $$
||f||_A = ||f||_p + ||f'||_p.
$$I want to show $A$ is a Banach space and that $T:A\to L^1[a,b]$ defined by $Tf =f$ is compact. If $(f_n)$ is some Cauchy sequence in $A$, then clearly as $||f_n-f_m||_p \le ||f_n-f_m||_A$ (and similarly for $(f'_n)$), both $(f_n)$ and $(f'_n)$ are Cauchy in $L^p[0,1]$. So they converge to some $f,g$ respectively. I think that if we can show $f' = g$ then we are done, although I'm not sure how to do this. I am trying to make some argument about $(Tg_n)$ having a convergent subsequence for some bounded sequence $(g_n)$ in $A$, although I'm having trouble doing this too.

Comment: Note that your space $A$ is the standard Sobolev space $W^{1,p}(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $f_n(x)=f_n(c)+\int_c^{x} f_n'(t)dt$. There is a subsequence of  $(f_n)$ converging a.e. to $f $. Let  $c $ be a point at which convergence holds.  Take limit in the equation along the subsequence to get $f(x)=f(c)+\int_c^{x}g(t)dt $. This implies that  $f'=g$ a.e.